# Ajax JQuery Issues in MVC 3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using https://github.com/Haacked/CodeHaacks
to access my MVC actions.

I've tried the sample local and it works fine.

However, when I put it in my code it gives the following error...

"Error: $mvc.ManageBanking.AddBank({Name: name}).done is not a function"

My code

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#NewBankButton').click(function () {
            var name = $('#txtBankName').val();

            $mvc.ManageBanking.AddBank({ Name: name }).done(function (data) {
                alert('done');
            });
        });
    });
```

Ajax Script

```
if (typeof $mvc === 'undefined') {
  $mvc = {};
}
$mvc.ManageBanking = [];
$.each(["AddBank","AddBankAccount"], function(action) {
 var action = this;
 $mvc.ManageBanking[this] = function(obj) {
   return $.ajax({
     cache: false,
     dataType: 'json',
     type: 'POST',
     headers: {'x-mvc-action': action},
     data: JSON.stringify(obj),
     contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
     url: '/json/managebanking?invoke&action=' + action
   });
 };
});
```

I was thinking it was my other script causing issues with it, but dont see anything that is messing with it... the method works because in my ManageBankingController, it steps through if I debug, but it doesnt go to the done event..

I was thinking "done" was wrong, but "success" doesnt work either..

Answer (score 0):

```
if (typeof $mvc === 'undefined') {
  $mvc = {};
}
$mvc.ManageBanking = {};
$.each(["AddBank","AddBankAccount"], function(index, action) {
 $mvc.ManageBanking[ action ] = function(obj) {
   return $.ajax({
     cache: false,
     dataType: 'json',
     type: 'POST',
     headers: {'x-mvc-action': action},
     data: JSON.stringify(obj),
     contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
     url: '/json/managebanking?invoke&action=' + action
   });
 };
});
```

Comment: this did not work.. however, as a workaround, I took out the $.ajax method and did it manually

Comment: Oh, i just noticed, `$mvc.ManageBanking` needs to be an object and not an array, the way you are accessing it `$mvc.ManageBanking.AddBank`

Comment: Given up on this... found a better solution instead.. https://github.com/zowens/ASP.NET-MVC-JavaScript-Routing